# Custom format document option in visual studio. Formatting CSS tags

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, indentation, readability, autoformatting

When i work in VS2008, i use the Ctrl+K+D very often as it saves a lot of time.

But in CSS files, this command formats the document in a way i don't quite like.

For example when i auto format the document,

```
.Foo
{
width:1px;
height:2px;
}
```

However, i like to format tags this way, as it is much more easy to read (in my opinion):

```
.Foo
{ width:1px;
  height:2px; }
```

So, are there any way that i can implement this ?

The "Tag specific options" feature seems to be the thing that i need, but i am not quite sure how to do this.

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.lonniebest.com/FormatCSS/

Comment: Thanks, i think this will be the closest alternative. I wish it was more customizable though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, after a long while i came up with an acceptable solution;

copy your css (or upload) to [this site](http://www.cleancss.com/) and at right, select "High (moderate readability, smaller size)"

and it will turn your css

```
.foo
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #ff0000;
}
```

into

```
.foo { font-weight: bold; color: #ff0000; }
```

(in my case, thats the one i wanted, you can select what you like most, there are five presets and other additional choices.)

Answer (score 7):

I just looked in the Visual Studio code formatting options and it appears that there are only three options you can choose from:

- Compact rules
- Semi-expanded
- Expanded

None of these meet your requirements. The formatting options for C# (and other languages) are much more customizable.

[image: Screenshot of the CSS text formatting options dialog in Visual Studio 2008]

Comment: Unfortunately, you are right. Still the only way is the 'manual' one.